# VB.NET Get RAM Serial Number like AIDA64

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, memory

I want to get the serial numbers abour my RAM modules.

I used this commands/solutions to get the serials:

```
wmic memorychip get serialnumber

ObjectQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_PhysicalMemory")
```

[image: https://i.gyazo.com/b0315483b994d0d3771d30619186a798.png]

These are showing absolutely nothing to me (null). After that, I tried AIDA64 and I can see the serials inside the program.

The question is: How can I get these serial numbers like AIDA64 in VB.NET?

I tried to find them in regedit, still nothing.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Where is the code you are using - is this really VB.NET?

Comment: I just showed an example for you. It means that I searched the serial number in "Win32_PhysicalMemory" but it's empty. I used this program too to get it: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17973/How-To-Get-Hardware-Information-CPU-ID-MainBoard-I

Actually, its working on some PC's and laptops, but for me it's says nothing while AIDA can show a serial for me. How? Where did AIDA64 gets the serial number from?

Comment: @Plutonix The first is a CMD prompt query...

Comment: If the command prompt works for you, then you could just try starting a cmd.exe process in the background and run that command...then the process's StandardOutput should contain your serial number

Comment: The problem is that it's not working. When I'm running that command it's showing empty rows. When I'm using AIDA64, it's showing me the serials. How? I'm intrested in how's AIDA64 knows the serials when I can't see anything. Nothing in CMD, nothing with vb.net but AIDA still knows it. How?